# Decompose nested JSON file to flat list with unique keys, using jq

Tags: json, key, grouping, jq, flatten

Given a JSON file of the format:

```
{
    "key00" : {
        "key10" : {
            "20170405" : {
                "val0" : 10,
                ...
                "valn" : 12
            }, 
            "20170404" : {
                "val0" : 5,
                ...
                "valn" : 43
            },
            ...
         },
         "key11" : {...},
         ...
     },
     "key01" : {...},
     "key02" : {...},
     ...
}
```

I want to use `jq` to decompose the tree into a flattened list whose format is such as below. This procedure should select one particular key in the hierarchy, the date, and for every instance of that date in the tree merge that date's values while making their key's unique based on the value's location in the tree:

```
[
    {
        "date" : "20170405",
        "key00.key10.val0" : 10,
        ...
        "key00.key10.valn" : 12
    },
    {
        "date" : "20170404",
        "key00.key10.val0" : 10,
        ...
        "key00.key10.valn" : 12
    },
    ...
    {
        "date" : "20170403",
        "key0n.key1n.val0" : 10,
        ...
        "key0n.key1n.valn" : 12
    },
]
```

Knowing the nesting structure, assuming it is rigid, I have performed this with a set of for-loops in Perl. But if the structure changes, the program breaks. Also, for every level of hierarchy, I need a for-loop. How would you go about traversing this tree recursively using jq's language?

(I want to use jq because I am already using it to merge many files together of the format in the first code listing, so I figure I could build upon that. The merge is simple: `jq -s 'reduce .[] as $x ({}, . * $x)' *.json > merged.json`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem like a rough ride, but to make things a bit more comprehensible, let's start with a helper function which will essentially make a JSON object when given an array of strings and a value, by creating a key from the array using a join character:

```
# input: [arrayOfStrings, value]
def squish(joinchar): { (.[0] | join(joinchar)): .[1] };
```

For example, `[["a","b"], 10] | squish(".")` emits `{"a.b", 10}`

The remainder of the solution to the problem is based on the built-in filters `paths` and `group_by`, which are documented elsewhere, but in brief, `paths` emits a stream of string arrays representing the paths; the associated value is then tacked on.  The [path, value] arrays are then grouped by date using `group_by`. Finally, the results are formatted according to the requirements.

```
. as $in
| [paths 
   | select(length==4)
   | . as $path
   | [ $path, ($in|getpath($path)) ] ]
| group_by( .[0][2] | tonumber )   # sort by numeric value
| map( {date: .[0][0][2] }
        + ( map( del(.[0][2]) | squish(".") ) | add) )
```

#### Caveats

1. The above solution groups paths globally by date, which seems to be in accordance with the requirements except for the sample output data.
2. The `select(length==4)` criterion that has been used above may have to be modified if the data differs from the sample given.

Comment: This is very interesting. I am in the process of digesting understand it. But, w.r.t. your caveat 1, yes that was a typo in the example data. I have corrected it.

Comment: This has opened up a whole new door for me in how I manipulate input data. Thank you!

Comment: I have it working and I basically have the whole sequence understood. What I do not get is the indexing. e.g. `group_by(.[0][2])`, the docs are not clear, I assume this means look at the first one in the array and it's third element, than group by that same element for the rest of the elements in the first level of the array. Something like `.[*][2]` if that was supported?

Comment: `.[0][2]` is simply short for `.[0] | .[2]`. If you don't understand the documents and examples, then I'd suggest using jq and/or jqplay (for example to get a better understanding of a built-in filter or pipeline).  Strategically placed `debug`s are also often helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution using **to_entries** to get at the data, put it into a form **setpath** will accept, **group_by** to organize by date and **reduce** with **setpath** to build the final form.

You can see how this works step by step.  First start with

```
  to_entries
| .[]
| .key as $k1
| ( .value | to_entries
           | $k1, .[] )
```

to get to the first key.  With my test data that gives me

```
"key00"
{
  "key": "key10",
  "value": {
    "20170405": {
      "val0": 10,
      "valn": 12
    },
    "20170404": {
      "val0": 5,
      "valn": 43
    }
  }
}
"key01"
...
```

then drill down a little more to get to the next key

```
  to_entries
| .[]
| .key as $k1
| ( .value | to_entries
           | .[]
           | .key as $k2
           | ( .value | to_entries
                      | $k1, $k2, .[] ) )
```

which gives

```
"key00"
"key10"
{
  "key": "20170405",
  "value": {
    "val0": 10,
    "valn": 12
  }
}
{
  "key": "20170404",
  "value": {
    "val0": 5,
    "valn": 43
  }
}
"key01"
"key11"
...
```

then a little more to get to the date and the final value

```
  to_entries
| .[]
| .key as $k1
| ( .value | to_entries
           | .[]
           | .key as $k2
           | ( .value | to_entries
                      | .[]
                      | .key as $d
                      | ( .value | to_entries
                                 | .[]
                                 | [$d, [$k1, $k2, .key], .value] ) ) )
```

Now that we have

```
[
  "20170405",
  [
    "key00",
    "key10",
    "val0"
  ],
  10
]
[
  "20170405",
  [
    "key00",
    "key10",
    "valn"
  ],
  12
]
...
```

put that back into an array and use **group_by**, **reduce** and **setpath**

```
[
  to_entries
| .[]
| .key as $k1
| ( .value | to_entries
           | .[]
           | .key as $k2
           | ( .value | to_entries
                      | .[]
                      | .key as $d
                      | ( .value | to_entries
                                 | .[]
                                 | [$d, [$k1, $k2, .key], .value]
                        )                
             )
   )
]
| group_by(.[0])
| .[]
| .[0][0] as $d
| reduce .[] as $e (
      {date:$d}
    ; setpath([$e[1] | join(".")]; $e[2])
  )
```

to get the final answer

```
{
  "date": "20170404",
  "key00.key10.val0": 5,
  "key00.key10.valn": 43
}
{
  "date": "20170405",
  "key01.key11.val1": 1,
  "key00.key10.valn": 12,
  "key00.key10.val0": 10,
  "key01.key11.val2": 2
}
{
  "date": "20170406",
  "key01.key11.val0": 0,
  "key01.key11.val9": 9
}
...
```